# Draw HSV circle at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to have a color picker in my app looking like this

[image: Something like this]

I've tried fill bitmap pixel by pixel, tried use canvas with `drawArc()` method. Both ways are not good for performance.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why does the color wheel have to be generated dynamically?  Why not just take the png shown in your question and display that?

Comment: It's not have to be, I just would like it to be generated dynamically to be 100% sure that coordinates correlate with colors correctly.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid programming question for a lot of android programmers trying to make a color picker. I could not agree less with the moderators that closed it. It is not narrow situation at all. You can find a code example of a color picker at http://www.buzzingandroid.com/2012/11/hsv-color-picker-dialog

Answer (score 4):

It might not be precisely what it should be (related to colors, saturation and so on), but [here is something](http://i1272.photobucket.com/albums/y391/mjeanson/hsv_circle.png) that start to look like what you want....

```
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public class HSV_Circle extends Drawable {
    Paint p = new Paint();

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        int width = canvas.getWidth();
        int height = canvas.getHeight();
        int min = Math.min(width,height);

        RadialGradient radial_gradient = new RadialGradient(width/2, height/2, min/2, 0xFFFFFFFF,
            0x00FFFFFF, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        int colors[] = new int[13];
        float hsv[] = new float[3];
        hsv[1]=1;
        hsv[2]=1;
        for (int i=0; i<12; i++) {
            hsv[0] = (360 / 12) * i;
            colors[i] = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
        }
        colors[12] = colors[0];

        SweepGradient sweep_gradient = new SweepGradient(width/2, height/2, colors, null);

        ComposeShader shader = new ComposeShader(sweep_gradient, radial_gradient, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER);

        p.setDither(true);
        p.setShader(shader);

        canvas.drawCircle(width/2, height/2, min/2, p);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int i) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.OPAQUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I said, I am not sure of the matching of colors versus position. I think the hue is ok, but the saturation might need some tweaking / thinking... at least, it's fast.... :)

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work in hardware-accelerated views. Only the radial gradient will be drawn. You have to disable hardware acceleration with the `View.setLayerType` method.